# How can hover image in ReactJs in by CSS file without use onMouseOut and onMouseHover

Tags: reactjs, image

I have a structure code like this:

```
<Row className="description d-flex justify-content-between">
    <Col className="social" as="a" href="/#">
        <Image className="social-icon" src={Facebook}
               onMouseOver={e => e.currentTarget.src = FBHover}
               onMouseOut={e => e.currentTarget.src = Facebook}
               alt="Facebook" />
    </Col>

    <Col className="social" as="a" href="/#">
    <Image className="social-icon" src={Youtube}
           onMouseOver={e => e.currentTarget.src = YoutubeHover}
           onMouseOut={e => e.currentTarget.src = Youtube}
           alt="Youtube" />
    </Col>

    <Col className="social" as="a" href="/#">
    <Image className="social-icon" src={Google}
           onMouseOver={e => e.currentTarget.src = GoogleHover}
           onMouseOut={e => e.currentTarget.src = Google}
           alt="Google" />
    </Col>
</Row>
```

In this case, I have a problem that. I shouldn't use `onMouseOut` and `onMouseOver` on this file. 
I must use `CSS` to hover and change that icon not as an event like that, also I could not use **Image tag for that**, I could use **image sprite**, can anyone help me for this case?

My image is put on **src/asses/icon** folder

Answer (score 0):

By using `class selector`  in *css* as follow :

```
.social-icon:hover {
   // add your styles on hover here
}
```

Comment: But how about my image src for that, my image is put on **src/asses/icon** how can I add for that CSS, my CSS file is put on `src/componets/Contact/index.css`

Comment: import Image from 'src/asses/icon' ...just type the right path of the image

Comment: this is in file CSS, right? `like this .social-icon:hover {
   url: "src/asses/icon...."
}`

Comment: No, in your component where you have image tag